# Cannot save strings into CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, xcdatamodel

I'm trying to save strings I have in my string array into the Core Data. My .xcdatamodel looks like this:

[image: .xcdatamodel]

My saving function (a method of a class called "Memory"):

```
func save(from: [String])
    {
        for i in 0..<from.count
        {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let saved = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: context)

            saved.setValue(from[i], forKey: "password")

            do
            {
                try context.save()
                print("SAVED")
            }

            catch
            {
                print("ERROR - COULDN'T SAVE ", to)
            }
        }

        print("NEW ", to, ": ")
        print(save)
    }
```

Lastly, inside my ViewController:

```
Memory().save(from: codes)
```

However, what I get is this:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration
>   failed, missing mapping model."
>   UserInfo={sourceModel=() isEditable
>   1, entities {
>
> Person = "() name Person,
>   managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier Person,
>   isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    password =
>   \"(), name password, isOptional
>   1, isTransient 0, entity

Answer (score 0):

You have made changes to your data model but you failed/forgot to migrate the model. If you don't have anything valuable in your current persistence store (SQLite database?) then I suggest you throw it away and let Core Data create a new one using the new model.

Otherwise you might want to fetch the previous version of your model from your source repository if you have one and do a proper migration. Here is a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492103/core-data-migration-problem-persistent-store-migration-failed-missing-source) of interest and [Apple's documentation on migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)